# boost::thread in-class member function call returns unique_lock instantiation error

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I am using `boost::thread` to call an in-class member function from within a different member function of the same class. The declaration of the method I would like to thread is:

```
void ClassName::nnMetropolisStep(double random, std::vector<int> nums);
```

And I am creating threads from another member function via:

```
boost::thread* tThread = new boost::thread(&ClassName::nnMetropolisStep,
                                           this,
                                           someRandom,someNums);
```

These are the only calls to `boost` functions in the code I'm using.

I've seen in other questions that this syntax will work for non-static member functions (and there are no access issues with the way I have constructed the threads). However, when I compile, I get the following error:

```
g++ -fPIC -std=c++11 -c -g -Wall `root-config --cflags --glibs` -MMD -c -o obj/IsingModel.o src/IsingModel.cpp
In file included from /usr/include/boost/thread/pthread/mutex.hpp:11:0,
             from /usr/include/boost/thread/mutex.hpp:16,
             from /usr/include/boost/thread/pthread/thread_data.hpp:12,
             from /usr/include/boost/thread/thread.hpp:17,
             from /usr/include/boost/thread.hpp:13,
             from src/interface/IsingModel.h:11,
             from src/IsingModel.cpp:11:
/usr/include/boost/thread/locks.hpp: In instantiation of 'boost::unique_lock<Mutex>& boost::unique_lock<Mutex>::operator=(boost::unique_lock<Mutex>&&) [with Mutex = boost::mutex]':
/usr/include/boost/thread/future.hpp:414:33:   required from here
/usr/include/boost/thread/locks.hpp:269:22: error: cannot bind  'boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex>' lvalue to 'boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex>&&'
         swap(temp);
                  ^
/usr/include/boost/thread/locks.hpp:279:14: note: initializing argument 1 of 'void boost::unique_lock<Mutex>::swap(boost::unique_lock<Mutex>&&) [with Mutex = boost::mutex]'
         void swap(unique_lock&& other)
          ^
make: *** [obj/IsingModel.o] Error 1
```

What is going on? Clearly I am either doing something incorrectly, or worse, there's an issue with my compiler setup.

Comment: You are getting error due to boost::unique_lock. Not due to the code mentioned by you here.

Comment: @Sumeet Yes, but why would I be getting that without any explicit calls or includes to unique_lock?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the answer by removing all references to `boost` except for the `#include` statement. In my header file, I was using

```
#include "boost/thread.hpp"
```

Which worked, but was not correct. Once I changed it to

```
#include "boost/thread/thread.hpp"
```

Everything compiled without complaint.

I'm using version `1.41.0` of boost.

Comment: You might want to update your Boost version some time. 1.41 is reeeeeally old. In particular, it predates the standardization of rvalue references, which is why its implementation does not work with C++11-conforming move semantics.

Comment: @ComicSansMS thanks for the heads up. Unfortunately, I have no control over the Boost distribution on the computing cluster I work on. I operate on whatever ROOT 6 will accept (which is not much!)

Comment: Sorry to hear that. In that case you might want to manually set the preprocessor define to disable rvalue reference support in Boost for your code, as Boost will have a different idea of what an rvalue is supposed to do than your compiler.

Comment: @ComicSansMS makes sense, but how significantly will doing so slow down my code? Would it make more sense to transition to pure pthread?

Comment: I wouldn't expect any significant slowdown in Boost.Thread because of that. It's more that some types in there are move-only (ie. you can't copy them, only move them), so you might have to jump through some hoops here and there to deal with this. But that's still nothing compared to the hoops that pthread makes you jump through every day.

Comment: helpful for me :)

Answer (score -2):

You need to use `boost::bind` function during thread object creation. For example:

```
    double rand = 0;
    std::vector<int> myVector;
    ClassName obj;
    auto threadObj = new        boost::thread(boost::bind(&ClassName::nnMetropolisStep,&obj,rand,myVector));
```

Comment: (1) No, `boost::bind` is used implicitly in the construction I use

(2) I am using this from within a non-static member function of a class. This means I cannot declare `ClassName` and pass it to `thread()`. I am passing `this` for good reason.